How to find a good profanity dictionary for English Words
I am finding a profanity dictionary for a music safety project.
I already found a good dataset (https://github.com/surge-ai/profanity), but I still need a data of this form that contains more categories of bad words:
Specifically, looking for violence, substance abuse, etc.
Best regards,
Johnson
